# JavaScript: .= don't works?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use something like PHP's .= to add multiple content to the same variable?

So far... I have this:

```
var img = '<li><img src="' + results[i].images.standard_resolution.url + '" />';

                    img .= '<a href="#" class="sb flat text twitter">Twitter</a>';
                    img .= '<a href="#" class="sb flat text twitter">Twitter</a>';

                    img .= '</li>';

                    sliderUL.append(img);
```

Sure I could create different variables names and just add them all... but I am wondering if there is any simpler/easier alternative.

Comment: funny and cute question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `+=` instead of `.=`, because `.=` is in php not javascript

```
 var img = '<li><img src="' + results[i].images.standard_resolution.url + '" />';
 img += '<a href="#" class="sb flat text twitter">Twitter</a>';
 img += '<a href="#" class="sb flat text twitter">Twitter</a>';
 img += '</li>';
 sliderUL.append(img);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the correct operator `+=`.

Answer (score 4):

The concatenation operator in JavaScript is `+=`.
The `.=` is a concatenation operator in PHP.

Change it to:

```
img += '<a href="#" class="sb flat text twitter">Twitter</a>';
img += '<a href="#" class="sb flat text twitter">Twitter</a>';

img += '</li>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use
x += "string"

PHP uses the period for concatenation
JavaScript uses the plus sign...

Answer (score -1):

It's not very efficient to keep concatenating strings together as this will result in poorly performing code if the strings become very large in size.

You would be better to keep pushing strings into an array and the joining the array with an empty string.